# Is it possible to create this illustration in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

This is just for learning purposes.

See the image in the link below. I want to learn how to create this vector. Is this possible to create with Adobe Illustrator? if yes, what is the method?

https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-vector-modern-colorful-flow-poster-wave-liquid-shape-in-blue-color-background-art-design-for-your-design-1017305410.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!

To do the shapes you should really add this image in the background and start to draw curves around edges. You would need a structure of multiple layers in order to create gradients, and if you look close you can estimate where each layer could be placed and where it ends.

The other way is to use the mesh tool once you draw all the curved layers. This might be the best way to add gradients to those shapes.